# How to subtract from Object elements using a loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to subtract the same amount derived in the working code below from each key value in the x object passed to my function, and then return the updated object so we pass

```
splitTheBill({A: 20, B: 15, C: 10})
```

to the function and we should return `{A: 5, B: 0, C: -5}` as the new object values.
I think I need a for loop to iterate through my object doing a subtraction of the shouldPay amount each iteration but I am now sure how to achieve this in Javascript. Help much appreciated TIA.

```js
function splitTheBill(x) {

  let toPayObject = {};
  let counter     = 0;
  let total       = 0;

  function sum(obj) {

    var sum = 0;

    for (var el in x) {
      if (x.hasOwnProperty(el)) {
        sum += parseInt(x[el]);
      }
    }
    return sum;
  }


  let amountPaid = sum(x);
  let shouldPay  = amountPaid / 3;

  console.log("Amount Paid £" + amountPaid + " Each person should pay:£" + shouldPay);

  return x;

}
```

Comment: Is this a school assignment?

Comment: Lol no it's a code wars kata solution I am working on try and get on a javascript bootcamp lol

Comment: remember mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

***IMPORTANT:*** *Scroll to bottom for "intended" solution.*

If I understand your question correctly (it's worded a little funky, also the represented example seems a bit odd), you want to sum the key values of your object, divide it by the amount of keys and return the values. I.e. sum the payment, divide it by amount of payees.

ES6 (or ES2015) has made this incredibly smooth by:

1. using the Object.values(obj) method, returning an array of the enumerable keys.
2. using the array.reduce method to sum the values.

Then what is left is to divide it by the length of the array (which amounts to the number of keys in the object).

***JS, using ES6 syntax:***

```
const sum = (bill) => {
    return Object.values(bill).reduce((a, b) => a + b);
};

const splitTheBill = (bill) => {
    return sum(bill) / Object.keys(bill).length;
};

const payees = {
    A: 20,
    B: 15,
    C: 10,
};

console.log(`Amount Paid £ ${sum(payees)}. Each person should pay: £ ${splitTheBill(payees)}.`);
```

***Snippet:***

```js
const sum = (bill) => {
    return Object.values(bill).reduce((a, b) => a + b);
};

const splitTheBill = (bill) => {
    return sum(bill) / Object.keys(bill).length;
};

const payees = {
    A: 20,
    B: 15,
    C: 10,
};

console.log(`Amount Paid £ ${sum(payees)}. Each person should pay: £ ${splitTheBill(payees)}.`);
```

---

***Edit:*** it has become clear that you intend to subtract the median value from each person's payment.

An object can be manipulated by accessing the keys and assigning new values. First, we need to know what the keys are. For that, we have the `Object.keys` method, which returns an array. Since we already know how to get an array of the object, we can perform a `forEach`, provide the index, fetch the key we want, use that as an index on the original object and then re-assign the value.

***JS, using ES6 syntax:***

```
const sum = (bill) => {
    return Object.values(bill).reduce((a, b) => a + b); // here we convert the object to an array, sum the values and return the result.
};

const splitTheBill = (bill) => {
    return sum(bill) / Object.keys(bill).length; // Here we divide the sum by the length of the object array. The length is equal to the number of keys in the object.
};

const subtractEqually = (bill) => {
    const splitValue = splitTheBill(bill); // How much each person should pay.
    const keys = Object.keys(bill); // Here we return an array with the keys of the original object.
    /*!
     * Loop through the object array, with the optional index parameter being provided.
     * The forEach loop takes 2 parameters, the second one being the index.
    !*/
    Object.values(bill).forEach((payment, index) => {
        /*!
         * Access the original object through its keys.
         * Since we have an array, containing the key names of the original object,
         * we can use the index value from our forEach as our pointer to each key name
         * as we iterate through the object array.
         * For instance, the keys array is equal to ["A", "B", "C"].
         * index 0 = "A", index 1 = "B", index 2 = "C". This is normal array indexing logic.
         * The original object, payees, has the key names that corresponds to what we have in the keys array.
         * For instance, payees["A"] will give us the object value for key "A".
         * So what we're doing in the end here, is simply accessing each key on the original object
         * E.g. payees["A"] will give us access to the value of key "A" in the object.
         * We can then assign this index to a new value, which is the original value minus the value we need to subtract.
        !*/
        payees[keys[index]] = payees[keys[index]] - splitValue;
    });
    
    return payees; // Return the object with the re-assigned values.
}

let payees = {
    A: 20,
    B: 15,
    C: 10,
};

console.log(`Amount Paid £ ${sum(payees)}. Each person should pay: £ ${splitTheBill(payees)}.`);
console.log(subtractEqually(payees));
```

***Snippet:***

```js
const sum = (bill) => {
    return Object.values(bill).reduce((a, b) => a + b);
};

const splitTheBill = (bill) => {
    return sum(bill) / Object.keys(bill).length;
};

const subtractEqually = (bill) => {
    const splitValue = splitTheBill(bill);
    const keys = Object.keys(bill);
    Object.values(bill).forEach((payment, index) => {
        payees[keys[index]] = payees[keys[index]] - splitValue;
    });
    
    return payees;
}

let payees = {
    A: 20,
    B: 15,
    C: 10,
};

console.log(`Amount Paid £ ${sum(payees)}. Each person should pay: £ ${splitTheBill(payees)}.`);
console.log(subtractEqually(payees));
```

Comment: Thanks Martin that's cool but I need to now find a way to subtract the same value from each key in the object and then return the new object with the new updated values any ideas 

Comment: @JonathanJoseph Ah, I understand now. Take a look at the edit. It should be what you're looking for (expected solution at the bottom).

Comment: That looks awesome Martin I am new to Javascript so I don't want to just copy and paste code lol. Any chance of sending me a quick one line comment on each piece of your code so I can grow my knowledge tia kind regards Jon

Comment: @JonathanJoseph I gave some explanations as to what is going on. If you need further elaboration on what each method does, i.e. the `reduce` method, you could always look it up on MDN. They have great docs and explanation of every method I provided in this example. If I were to give any further explanation myself, it'd just be to copy paste that from MDN, which is pretty redundant if you ask me. They already do a great job at explaining it afterall.

Comment: Thanks Martin much appreciated have a great evening 

Comment: @JonathanJoseph Feel free to accept the answer etc. Also provided comments now, in case it helps.